# Javascripts work in chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am doing some validation with javascript. It is fine in Chrome but as usual IE is playing up

My code is below

```
function check(a,id){ 

  inputs = document.getElementsByName('attname[]');
  for (var ind in inputs){
    if (inputs[ind].value=="") {
      alert("Please complete every participant");
      return false;
    }
  } 

  $("#UserForm").submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Two issues I see. You forgot to declare `inputs`, and you should be looping with a regular `for` loop. Not sure about the IE problem though. Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what the actual problem is ("playing up" isn't really a helpful description ;)), nor which IE versions you're testing with, but I guess IE9 or earlier.

Your problem is probably due to the fact that `document.getElementsByName()` has bugs and is not properly implemented in IE9 and earlier. (It is fine in IE10 though).

You can see a full browser-compatibility chart [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/), along with notes about the bugs in IE.

The solution depends on which IE versions you need to support.

If you're happy with supporting IE8 and later, you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead. This selects elements using a CSS selector, so you can do something like this:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name=attname\\[\\]]');
```

This would be a direct replacement for your existing `getElementsByName()` call, and will work in all IE version from IE8 upward, and in all other browsers.

Note that with this syntax, you'll have to backslash-escape the `[]` characters, as they're reserved characters in CSS. (and the reason the backslashes are doubled up is because you also have to escape backslashes in Javascript strings).

This syntax won't work in IE7 as it isn't supported ((see here for browser support info)[http://caniuse.com/queryselector]), so if you need to support IE7 you'll have to find an alternative solution. My recommendation is to use a library like jQuery, because otherwise you'll just spend ages fighting with IE7's limited DOM functionality. Or you could just drop IE7 support: that would also be a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use JQUery for the rest of the stuff aswell and not only for submitting the form.

JQuery takes care of browser issues, is easy to use, slim and an abstraction layer for compatiblity issues for JavaScript across different browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(a, id) {
        $("[name=attname]").each(function() {
            if(($this).val() == "") {
                alert("Please complete every participant");
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We don't know if he's using jQuery, eg: `function $(sel){return document.querySelector(sel)}`

Comment: Look at his last line of code?
$("#UserForm").submit();
If this is not JQuery, what else?

But thanks for downvote without reading anyway...

Comment: Wasn't my downvote but look at my top comment, it could be that or similar. That's why I was asking if OP's using jQuery or not...

Comment: No it is just javascript I am using for this